# Selection of text in AutoCAD through Lisp or Script

Tags: text, autocad, autolisp

I am trying to think of a way to have some type of script or macro select a phrase of text then edit it and bolden it. However the only thing I've found that works is Qselect which didn't work in the macro I recorded or work in any scripts (that I know of). Looking for a solid spot to start from on this.

Basically so far I just did QSelect>"MTEXT">MTEDIT>Ctrl+A>Ctrl+B

Thanks

Comment: Can we get some more context, like why you're trying to do this and under what circumstances? Does this need to work on MText and Text objects, or just MText? You want to bolden an entire text block or just a phrase within a block? One at a time or multiple blocks at a time, or all the text objects?

Comment: Sure thing, when I kick out a drawing from a separate program (where I can't bolden it) I need to take one of the Revs and bolden it. When it's kicked out it's it's own Text block (but figured if someone could help me figure out the Qselect, then doing the Qselect for changing TXT2MTEXT would be easier). Usually there are a lot of drawings so looking for a way to just flip through them faster and just seems like there has to be an easier way than opening every drawing.

Answer (score 0):

#### Obtaining a Selection

You cannot automate the `QSELECT` command.

You will need to obtain a selection using the `ssget` function with the `"X"` mode string (to query the drawing database automatically), and an appropriate filter list to target the desired text.

Since you mention the use of the `TXT2MTXT` command in your comment, I'm going to assume that the initial 'text block' is single-line text (`TEXT`).

To obtain a selection of single-line text you can use an `ssget` expression such as:

```
(ssget "_X" '((0 . "TEXT")))
```

However, this will return **all** single-line text objects residing in **all** drawing layouts.

Therefore, you will need to refine the filter list supplied to the `ssget` function to target the specific instance(s) of single-line text that you require.

This could be achieved by filter by layout, e.g.:

```
(ssget "_X" '((0 . "TEXT") (410 . "MyLayout")))
```

By layer, e.g.:

```
(ssget "_X" '((0 . "TEXT") (8 . "MyLayer")))
```

Or by any other property or combination of properties which uniquely distinguish your target single-line text from all other text in the drawing.

You may wish to refer to my [ssget reference](http://lee-mac.com/ssget.html) for more information and examples surrounding the use of `ssget` with filter lists.

#### Conversion from TEXT to MTEXT

Upon obtaining an appropriate selection set of single-line text objects, you will first need to generate a multiline text object (`MTEXT`) with the same properties as each single-line text object, as `TEXT` cannot display bold type.

To do this, you will need to iterate over the selection set obtained above. I provide several methods demonstrating how to do this in my tutorial on [Selection Set Processing](http://lee-mac.com/selsetprocessing.html).

For each `TEXT` object, you can either issue a call to the `TXT2MTXT` function (though, note that since this is an Express Tools command, you will need to evaluate it as a LISP function, not an in-built AutoCAD commmand), and then collect the `MTEXT` objects which have been added to the drawing database (i.e. using a combination of `entlast` & `entnext`). Alternatively, you could generate an `MTEXT` entity using the `entmake` function and DXF properties obtained from the DXF data of the `TEXT` entity (using `entget`) - this is the way that I would personally approach the problem.

#### Applying a Bold Typeface

Text Style overrides (such as bold, italic, underline, overline) are represented using MText Formatting Codes embedded within the MText content.

For bold text, you will need to surround the existing MText content with the following MText Formatting Codes:

```
{\\f<FontFace>|b1|i0|c0|p18;<Existing Text Content>}
```

Here, the `b1` indicates that the bold version of `<FontFace>` will be used.